# getApplicationContext error

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-context, amazon-sns

I'm trying to store my device token from my android app programmatically to AWS SNS platform application.

I'm getting an error in `getApplicationContext()` method. Anyone with a solution for this error?

This is my code:

```
public class RegisterIdForAWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private Exception exception;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            String pushNotificationRegId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

            if (pushNotificationRegId != null) {

                CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider provider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                       getApplicationContext(),
                        "us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        Regions.US_WEST_2);
                String platformApplicationArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:11111111111:app/GCM/123";
                AmazonSNSClient pushClient = new AmazonSNSClient(provider);
                pushClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));

                String customPushData = "";
                CreatePlatformEndpointRequest platformEndpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
                platformEndpointRequest.setCustomUserData(customPushData);
                platformEndpointRequest.setToken(pushNotificationRegId);
                platformEndpointRequest.setPlatformApplicationArn(platformApplicationArn);
                CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = pushClient.createPlatformEndpoint(platformEndpointRequest);
                Log.w(TAG, "Amazon Push reg result: " + result);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String text) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Amazon Push reg Finished");
    }


}
```

Comment: In which Activity you are using this AsyncTask and give proper flow with details so answer can  be deliverd properly. Otherwise answer below given by the @Andrea Ebano was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In constructor of your async class, pass Context

```
private Context mContext;

public RegisterIdForAWS (Context context){
     mContext = context;
}
```

And instantiate class like this:

```
RegisterIdForAWS task = new RegisterIdForAWS (context);
```

Hope it helps.